# False (or misleading) NuGet package compatibility error

Tags: nuget

The dependencies have changed in several of the packages I'm using, so I called

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

It gave me this error, which makes no sense to me.  Any pointers as to where the problem might lie?

```
Attempting to resolve dependencies for multiple packages.
Update-Package : Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Expression.Interaction 3.0.40218' is not compatible with 'MyLib 5.0.0.17-pilot constraint: 
Expression.Interaction (>= 3.0.40218)'.At line:1 char:1
+ Update-Package –reinstall
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Update-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UpdatePackageCommand
```

Comment: What do you mean by false compatibility error? Is that compatibility error not supposed to be true?

Comment: @SeanWang hi Sean. The version of Expression.Interaction matches the constraint perfectly, and yet it complains! I'm sure there must be something more subtle going on - but the error gives me no clue at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message was indeed misleading.  However, Nuget 3.5 now shows extra warnings about unsatisfied dependencies, and the answer lay here.